# Map array using children of parent component to reference object properties (NextJS / React)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am running into a little issue that I can't seem to solve. I am trying to map an array using the JSX elements from the children of the parent component, but don't know how to use "item" correctly from the parent component. The idea is to have a dynamic child component that I can send different styles of children that make use of the item's properties in the child:

```
export default function Parent() {
  <Child array={[ { name: 'Spencer' }, { name: 'Jimmy' }, { name: 'Frank' } ]}>
    <div>{item.name}</div>
  </Child>

  <h1>Another example of sending different children to the Child component</h1>
  <Child array={[ { name: 'Spencer' }, { name: 'Jimmy' }, { name: 'Frank' } ]}>
    <h1>{item.name}</h1>
    <p>Name of player</p>
  </Child>
}

export default function Child({array, children}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((item) => {
        {children}
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried referencing the item from the map property in the parent component, but that obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function inside `Parent`, and pass `item` into it when mapping in `Child`.

```js
function Parent() {
  return (
  <Child array={[{ name: 'Spencer' }, { name: 'Jimmy' }, { name: 'Frank' }]}>
    {(item) => <div>{item.name}</div>}
  </Child>
  )
}

function Child({array, children}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((item) => children(item))}
    </div>
  )
}  

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, app)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me hours of work. Can't believe it was something as simple as that. Had no idea you could pass a function like that. This is going to be a powerful tool for me. Thanks

Comment: Anytime! Happy to help! I didn't know it'd work at first, but this solidified to me that `children` is a normal prop in the end, just sandwiched between two tags instead of an attribute in the first tag. We just normally pass it JSX.